# O que é lematização?

Tags: gramática

O que é? Quais construções podem ser consideradas lematizadas?

Gostaria de alguns exemplos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A lematização é o processo, efetivamente, de deflexionar uma palavra para determinar o seu **lema** (as flexões chamam-se **lexemas**)

Por exemplo, as palavras *gato, gata, gatos, gatas* são todas formas do mesmo lema: *gato*.<sup>1</sup> Igualmente, as palavras *tiver, tenho, tinha, tem* são do mesmo lema *ter*. E *bom, melhor* e *ótimo* são lexemas do lema *bom*.

A lematização é útil quando queremos ver os usos de palavras em contextos sem importância das flexões. Por exemplo, para a criação e uso de índices ou na investigação linguística. Ninguém quer ficar obrigado a pesquisar todas as formas duma palavra para encontrá-la num texto. Se pesquisássemos *gato*, seria melhor ter quaisquer das quatro formas como resultado, não só a forma masculina singular.  Ou ao investigar as preferências entre «ter de» e «ter que», seria possível pesquisar as ocorrências em toda flexão do verbo com uma pesquisa como *TER<sub>lema</sub> de* em vez de construir uma pesquisa como *ter de + tenho de + tens de + tem de + temos de + …*

---

<sup>1. Tecnicamente, não há razão precisa por que o lema tenha de ser o infinitivo (com os verbos) ou a forma masculina singular (com os adjetivos e alguns substantivos), é simplesmente tradição porque são as formas que usa um dicionário.  Poderíamos haver dito «gatX» por o lema de *gato* se quiséssemos usar uma forma que não coincidisse com um dos lexemas, e de fato, os sistemas informáticos soem assinar números.</sup>